# Pasar de pseudocódigo a código python

Tags: python

tengo el siguiente pseudocódigo y lo trate de implementar en python de la siguiente manera, me podrían decir si esta bien o que deberia cambiarle?

Pseudocódico:

```
   FUNC Embarcaderos ( ↓ origen, destino, n: NATURAL, ↓ T: MATRIZ DE NATURALES): NATURAL
   Variables
       C: MATRIZ DE NATURALES
       i, j: NATURAL
   Inicio
       PARA i = 1 HASTA n HACER
           C[i][i] := 0
       FIN PARA
       PARA i = 1 HASTA n HACER
           PARA j = 1 HASTA n HACER
               C[i][j] := menorDeLosCandidatos(i, j, n, T, C)
           FIN PARA
       FIN PARA
       devolver C[n] [n]
   Fin
```

Y el código implementado en python es el siguiente: En la línea C[i][i]=0 me sale el error de "list index out of range"

```
def Embarcaderos ( origen, destino, n, T):
    C = []
    i=1
    j=1
    for i in range(n):
        C[i][i]=0
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            C[i][j] = menorDeLosCandidatos(i, j, n, T, C)
    return C[n][n]       

def menorDeLosCandidatos (origen, destino, n, T, C):
       temp = max
       for i in [origen+1,n]:
           temp = min(temp,T[origen][i] + C[i][destino])

       return temp

T= [[10,40,100],[0,20,80],[0,0,5]] 
Embarcaderos(1,4,4, T)
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que esta tratando de acceder un indice de un array que no existe. La solucion es verificar que el array existe y iniciarlo si no existe.

Por ejemplo, en esa linea:

```
C[i][i]=0
```

Se puede cambiarla a eso:

```
try:
  C[i][i]=0
except IndexError:
  C[i] = []
  C[i][i] = 0
```

Comment: Pero en si, el pseudocódigo esta bien implementado?

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que la línea de pseudocódigo que decía:

```
       C: MATRIZ DE NATURALES
```

La has escrito como:

```
    C = []
```

que no es una matriz sino una lista vacía. Al estar vacía, no podrás acceder después a ninguno de sus elementos. Por ejemplo `C[i]` sería el elemento `i`-ésimo de esa lista, pero al no existir te dará error. Incluso si existiera, se supone que ese primer elemento habría de ser otra lista, pues intentas luego hacer `C[i][i]`, que sería el elemento `i`-ésimo dentro de la lista que está en posición `i`-ésima dentro de `C`.

Por tanto no sirve la inicialización `C=[]`. Debes en cambio inicializar `C` con una lista de listas.

El problema es que no está claro cuántos elementos ha de tener `C`, ni cuántos elementos ha de tener cada una de sus sub-listas. De todas formas ya que luego intentarás acceder a sus elementos `[i][i]` en un bucle que itera `n` veces, cabe suponer que la matriz `C` ha de ser cuadrada y de tamaño `n*n`.

Otro problema es que no puedes crear una matriz de `n*n` "sin más", es decir, sin especificar qué valores tienen todos sus elementos. A diferencia de otros lenguajes en C no puedes simplemente pedir algo como "reserva aquí memoria para `n*n` enteros". En lugar de eso debes decir algo como "Sea `C` una lista con los siguientes valores:" y dar la lista de valores seguidamente.

Por tanto tenemos que pensar qué valores dar inicialmente a todos los elementos de `C`. Creo que una buena idea podría ser rellenarla entera con ceros. Esto puedes hacerlo de dos formas, una relativamente directa (y un poco tediosa), que sería crearla primero vacía y en un bucle ir añadiendo filas mediante `.append()`. Cada fila a su vez se crearía también vacía y se le irían añadiendo ceros mediante `.append()`. Así:

```
C = []
for i in range(n):
  fila = []
  for j in range(n):
    fila.append(0)
  # Al salir de aqui tenemos la fila creada, la añadimos a C
  C.append(fila)
```

Al terminar estos bucles `C` tendría por ejemplo (para `n=4`):

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Otra forma más compacta de hacer lo mismo (pero cuya sintaxis te parecerá rara si no conoces las comprensiones de listas, o el hecho de que el operador `*` sobre una lista sirve para repetir el mismo elemento varias veces) sería la siguiente:

```
C = [ [0]*n for i in range(n) ]
```

Esa única línea produciría el mismo resultado respecto a la matriz `C`.

A partir de aquí ya podrías acceder sin problemas a `C[i][i]` (para `i<n`). Pero fíjate que ahora ya es supérfluo el bucle en que rellenabas la diagonal con ceros, pues ya está de todas formas llena de ceros la matriz completa. Podrías omitir por tanto esa parte del pseudocódigo.

**Nota adicional**. Las asignaciones `i=1; j=1` que haces al principio son también innecesarias en python. Las variables se crearán de todas formas en el momento de usarlas por primera vez, lo cual ocurre un poco después en los bucles `for`

Respecto a la función `menorDeLosCandidatos()`, ya que no has especificado qué debe hacer esa función ni el pseudocódigo de la misma, no es posible decirte si tu implementación está correcta o no. Pero ya de mano tiene un error de sintaxis en la primera línea, en que haces:

```
       temp = max
```

pues `max` es el nombre de una función python. Estarías aquí asignando a la variable `temp` una función, lo cual es legal en python, pero eso te causará problemas más adelante cuando intentes comparar `temp` con otros números, ya que `temp` no es un número y el intento de comparación dará error.

Supongo que lo que se pretendía en esa línea es asignarle a `temp` un valor que sea mayor a cualquiera de los elementos que se encontrará después. La única solución que se me ocurre es asignarle un número enorme, que sepas seguro que no puede aparecer entre los datos de entrada. Por ejemplo 1000000.

Hay más problemas en el código:

- Por ejemplo tu intento de retornar `C[n][n]` va a fallar siempre, pues en python los arrays se numeran desde 0 hasta `n-1`. No está claro qué debe retornar la función ¿el último elemento de la diagonal? En ese caso sería `C[n-1][n-1]`.
- Cuando llamas a la función le pasas `n=4`, y sin embargo la matriz `T` es de 3x3. Eso causará problemas al intentar acceder a `T[origen][i]` pues `i` puede llegar a tomar valores por encima de la dimensión de `T`.
- El bucle `for i in [origen+1,n]:` es bastante raro. Sospecho que en realidad querías hacer `for i in range(origen+1, n)` pero sin saber qué se supone que hace el algoritmo es difícil saberlo.

En general, para ayudarte mejor, creo que sería necesario no sólo el pseudocódigo, sino una descripción de qué se supone que hace ese algoritmo, y un ejemplo de qué salida debería producir para una cierta entrada.

Answer (score 0):

Proceso Compañia_telefonica
definir minutos,turno,dia,error Como Entero
definir precio, impuesto,total como real

```
    /// Definir variables   
    impuesto= 0
    error =0
    
    escribir "Ingresar los minutos"
    leer minutos 
    si minutos <= 5 entonces 
        precio = minutos *.10
    SiNo
        si minutos <= 8 entonces 
            precio =((minutos-5)*.80)+.50
        SiNo
            si minutos <= 10 Entonces
                precio =((minutos-8)*.70)+2.90
            SiNo
                precio = ((minutos-10)*.50)+4.30
            FinSi
        FinSi
    FinSi
    escribir "Ingresa un numero deacuerdo al dia"
    escribir "1 = Domingo"
    escribir "2 = Otro dia"
    leer dia
    si dia == 1 entonces 
        impuesto = precio *.03
    SiNo
        si dia == 2 entonces 
            escribir "Ingresa un numero de acuerdo al turno"
            escribir " 1 = Mañana"
            escribir " 2 = Tarde"
            leer turno 
            si turno == 1 entonces 
                impuesto = precio *.15
            SiNo
                si turno == 2 entonces 
                    impuesto = precio *.10
                SiNo
                    escribir "Ingresa un turno correcto"
                    error = 1
                FinSi
            FinSi
        SiNo
            escribir "Ingresar un dia correcto"
            error = 1
        FinSi
    FinSi
    si error == 0 Entonces
        total = precio + impuesto
        escribir "El total a pagar por ",minutos," minutos de llamda es:$",total
        escribir "El impuesto aplicado es:$",impuesto
    FinSi
```

FinProceso

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).